# Where does Microsoft Office Add-ins manifest get locale from?

Tags: ms-word, locale, office-js, manifest, office-addins

I have a Word add-in defined by a manifest xml file with the following overriding:

```
<DefaultLocale>en-AU</DefaultLocale>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="[DEV] My Add-in">
    <Override Locale="en-au" Value="[en-au] My Add-in" />
    <Override Locale="en-ca" Value="[en-ca] My Add-in" />
    <Override Locale="en-us" Value="[en-us] My Add-in" />
</DisplayName>
<SupportUrl DefaultValue="url-default">
    <Override Locale="en-au" Value="url-au" />
    <Override Locale="en-ca" Value="url-ca" />
    <Override Locale="en-us" Value="url-us" />
</SupportUrl>
```

I want to test whether the overriding works when my add-in gets loaded in different regions. However, the add-in somehow always shows en-us config (`[en-us] My Add-in` and `url-us` for SupportUrl).

What I have done before re-inserting my dev add-in from shared folder:

- pick another region/language/time-zone
- cleared my `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\` folder
- change language settings in all browser types and clear the cache
- change language preference in Word

The only thing US left I can find in my machine is the Window display language (which I have no other option to choose) and the keyboard, but I don't think that's where Word task pane gets locale code from.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right place for testing this locale overriding.

Comment: What do the[ Office.Context.displayLanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.context#displayLanguage) and Office.Context.contentLanguage properties return at runtime?

Comment: Also, what do you see when you navigate in the ribbon to  File > Options > Language?

Comment: Hi Rick, Office.Context.displayLanguage returns en-US, Office.Context.contentLanguage returns en-CA.

Comment: In File > Options > Language, for Office display language, I have Match MS Windows [English] <preferred> and for Office authoring languages and proofing I have English (Canada) <preferred>.

Comment: To test your overrides, you should go to  File > Options > Language and change to a different language. Then reload the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

When re-adding the Manifest put in a new  value or Office seems to cache some of the setting.